# Node.js file write issue, incomplete writing

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am new to node.js I wrote a **scraper** as below and result it produces is not fine. All entries are not being written and incomplete broken data is being added to file, though individual data extraction if fine in console log.

The original file is complex sample from all code parts I have added to show my logic please tell what is being done wrong.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = 'http://example.com/index.html';
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    $ = cheerio.load(body);   
    var categoryname = $('#mcat span').html();
    var subcategoryname = $('span.arrow').html();
    $('.listing').each(function() {
    var companyname = $(this).find('.company-name > span').html();
    var compwebsite = $(this).find('.company-link > a').html();
    var phonelumber = "+91-" + $(this).find('span[itemprop="telephone"]').html();
            

        var data = categoryname + ", " + subcategoryname + ", " + companyname + ", " + phonelumber;
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFile("data.txt", data, function(err) {
        if(err) {
        console.log("Error: "+err);
        } else {
        console.log("Success!");
        }
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me, according to your need. Where is the problem in this??

Comment: Data is extracted fine but may be issue is in writing in loop ".each(" don't know why but all records are not being written line by line only 1 2 broken lines are being added.
May be issues is with synchronicity or something as I am not familiar with nodejs

Comment: Then you must be having problems employing proper callbacks in your code.

Comment: This is all the code, I didn't need callback anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`.each` is called synchronously, hence it is blocking. But the `fs.writeFile` is called asynchronously so it makes your data to shuffle, but no way it is going to be incomplete.

**Solutions**:

*Use Callback*

```
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var categoryname = $('#mcat span').html();
    var subcategoryname = $('span.arrow').html();
    var count = 0;
    var len = $('.listing').length;
    var data = '';
    $('.listing').each(function() {
        count++;
        var companyname = $(this).find('.company-name > span').html();
        var compwebsite = $(this).find('.company-link > a').html();
        var phonelumber = "+91-" + $(this).find('span[itemprop="telephone"]').html();
        data += categoryname + ", " + subcategoryname + ", " + companyname + ", " + phonelumber + "\r\n";
        if(count == len)
             writeData(data);
    });
});

function writeData(data) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("data.txt", data, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        } else {
            console.log("Success!");
        }
    });
}
```

2. *Use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) module*. It has various usable functions to apply callback and get the necessary result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also do it easier (just call the writedata function after the each loop (because cherio's each() is synchronous, so there will be no problem)

```
    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var categoryname = $('#mcat span').html();
    var subcategoryname = $('span.arrow').html();
    var data = '';
    $('.listing').each(function() {
        var companyname = $(this).find('.company-name > span').html();
        var compwebsite = $(this).find('.company-link > a').html();
        var phonelumber = "+91-" + $(this).find('span[itemprop="telephone"]').html();
        data += categoryname + ", " + subcategoryname + ", " + companyname + ", " + phonelumber + "\r\n";
    });
    writeData(data);
});

function writeData(data) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("data.txt", data, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        } else {
            console.log("Success!");
        }
    });
}
```